# Unpack json in php

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am trying to unpack my json object send via http post request in a php controller:

```
        $products = $_POST['products'] ?? '';

        foreach($products as $purchase){
        $productId =$purchase['productid'];
        $qty = $purchase['quantity'];
        $params = array(
                      'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                      'product' => $productId,
                      'qty'   => $qty
                  );
          //Load the product based on productID
          $_product = $this->product->load($productId);
          $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
          $this->cart->save();
      }
```

This is the format of my json object being sent, stored in a variable called `list`.

```
0: {productid: "2910", quantity: "2"}
1: {productid: "2911", quantity: "1"}
2: {productid: "2913", quantity: "4"}
3: {productid: "2914", quantity: "3"}
```

This is my post request (content type is also set to `application/json`):

```
$.post("http://dev.website.co.uk/batchorder/index/addtocart",
    {
      products:list,
    },
    function(data, status){
      console.log("Data: " + data);
      console.log("Status: " + status);
    });
```

This has always worked for me before so i cannot see where i am going wrong with it.

The error i am getting is `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. but i am assuming it has something to do with my json object.

EDIT:

```
$("#AddToCartButton").click(function(){
   var list = [];
   $("#tabCollection :input").each(function(){
   var input = $(this);
    if($(this)[0].value > 0){
      var myArray = {'productid': $(this)[0].id, 'quantity': $(this)[0].value};
      list.push(myArray);
    }
   });
   var JSONStringlist = JSON.stringify(list);
   var JSONlist = JSON.parse(JSONStringlist);
   console.log(JSONlist);

   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers:{
       'Content-Type': "application/json",
      }
   });

   $.post("http://dev.website.co.uk/batchorder/index/addtocart",
    {
      "products":JSONlist,
    },
    function(data, status){
      console.log("Data: " + data);
      console.log("Status: " + status);
    });
  });
```

EDIT 2:

example of JSON String:

```
[{"productid":"2182","quantity":"1"},{"productid":"2183","quantity":"1"},{"productid":"2184","quantity":"1"},{"productid":"2185","quantity":"1"}]
```

Comment: My guess the foreach on $products produces the error. $products is either  a string or whatever the posted value contains, did you json_decode the posted value? Maybe a better default would be an array?

Comment: Can you make a var_export($products) to see the content?

Comment: Hi John, i did try using json_decode() on the $products variable but this did not work either..

Comment: json_decode($products, true) to convert to array

Comment: Just for curiosity what does `?? '';` stands for?

Comment: @SebastienD, https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary

Comment: @SebastienD null coalesce operator

Comment: im fairly new to php so someone correct me if i am wrong but i believe it is a turnary operator? and what it does is say if the POST[''} value is empty then set the variable as '' instead. it is essential an "else if"

Comment: So shoudn't this be `?? [];` in this case?

Comment: probably should @SebastienD

Comment: What exactly is your `list` variable in javascript, is it a string or an object? And can you post the exact contents? What you have shown is not valid json nor is it an object...

Comment: Ha, learned something new from inspecting this question. Passing a raw js array like `var list = [{'var1':'val1'},{'var2':'val2'}]`... in jquery ajax `data: {list:list}`, converts it to `list%5B0%5D%5Bvar1%5D:val1` `list%5B1%5D%5Bvar2%5D:val2` ... so PHP ends with `$_POST['list'][0]['var1'] = 'val1'` `$_POST['list'][0]['var2'] = 'val2'`. I did not know jquery did this with a raw js array in that manner. *drr*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $products = $_POST['products'] ?? '';

    foreach($products as $purchase){
```

Your $products is either "something that is iterable" or a empty string.

In case it's a array, it's iterable, and the foreach will succesfully execute. But in case it's a empty string, it's going to complain about "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", cause a string is not really iterable.

So what you need to do is make sure, that $products is always an array, either an empty or filled with json objects.

If you change:

```
$products = $_POST['products'] ?? '';
```

to:

```
$products = json_decode($_POST['products']) ?? array();
```

The foreach won't complain, and if $_POST['products'] is empty nothing will be saved in the cart.

In your javascript file change:

```
$.post("http://dev.website.co.uk/batchorder/index/addtocart",
    {
      "products":JSONlist,
    },
    function(data, status){
      console.log("Data: " + data);
      console.log("Status: " + status);
    });
  });
```

to:

```
$.post("http://dev.website.co.uk/batchorder/index/addtocart",
    {
      "products":JSONStringlist,
    },
    function(data, status){
      console.log("Data: " + data);
      console.log("Status: " + status);
    });
  });
```

You are parsing an JavaScript object to JSON, and then you're reparsing it back to an JavaScript object.

PHP does not really understand JavaScript objects, but understands JSON objects.

Comment: It will still complain when `products` is passed, because `$_POST['products']` is never going to be an array based on his ajax code provided.

Comment: He is trying to send an empty list, or an "non iterable object". With high probability, he is sending an JSON array, which needs to be parsed to a php array. But since we can't see preceding lines of code before $_POST['products'];, it's impossible to say if it's parsed to PHP or not.

Comment: Thanks for this. im slowly peicing it together. You were correct about it trying to iterate an empty string. I was passing through the raw Jquery array.

What format should the array be sent in, JSON?

Comment: Send it as JSON, and in PHP do the following... (I'll edit my post 2 sec)

Comment: Can you test? by the way, you should make some validation on the data received.

Comment: just tried it and i still cant get it to work. I appreciate the help, thank you. I have posted more a the JS in my post

Comment: Change       "products":JSONlist,
to       "products": JSONStringlist,

Comment: I do not know why it is not working.. data is definitely being sent to the controller

Comment: whoops didnt mean to start a chat

Comment: Did you try with the change I mentioned above?